# Evaluation of limit $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x + e^{-x} -2}{x^2}$

Tags: calculus, solution-verification, limits-without-lhopital

**I've been given to evaluate the limit,**
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x + e^{-x} -2}{x^2}$$

---

**Here's my approach to the problem:**
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x + e^{-x} -2}{x^2}$$
$$\implies\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(e^x  -1)+(e^{-x} -1)}{x^2}$$
$$\implies\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(e^x  -1)}{x^2}+\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(e^{-x} -1)}{x^2}$$
$$\implies\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(e^x  -1)}{x}\cdot\frac{1}x+\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(e^{-x} -1)}{x}\cdot \frac1x$$
$$\implies\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}x-\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(e^{-x} -1)}{-x}\cdot \frac1x$$
$$\implies\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}x-\frac1x$$
$$\implies0$$

---

But solving using another method,
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x + e^{-x} -2}{x^2}$$
$$\implies\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x + \dfrac1{e^x} -2}{x^2}$$
$$\implies\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^{2x}-2e^x + 1}{e^x\cdot x^2}$$
$$\implies\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(e^{x}-1)^2}{x^2}\cdot\frac1{e^x}$$
$$\implies\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{e^x}$$
$$\implies 1$$

---

Why are these two methods giving two different results? I know that the first method is incorrect, but don't actually know what's the mistake. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you allowed to assume that $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{e^x - 1}{x} = 1$?  This is sometimes done using L'Hopital's.  So, you might have to find that limit too.

Comment: Well, that's a standard result, I don't think I need to show the steps for this limit too @J126

Comment: As I recall, the difference of the limits isn't the limit of the difference if the individual limits are both infinity. I think that applies whether or not the functions are undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it is true that that you can break up limits $\lim_\limits{x\to a} f(x) g(x) = \lim_\limits{x\to a} f(x) \lim_\limits{x\to a} g(x)$ and $\lim_\limits{x\to a} f(x) + g(x) = \lim_\limits{x\to a} f(x)+\lim_\limits{x\to a} g(x)$
You can only do it if $\lim_\limits{x\to a} f(x)$ and $\lim_\limits{x\to a} g(x)$ exist and are finite.

Where you have: $\lim_\limits{x\to 0} \frac {e^x - 1}{x}\frac {1}{x}$ you cannot evaluate the first factor as the limit does not exist for the second factor.

This line is not correct either:

$\lim_\limits{x\to 0} \frac {(e^x - 1) + (e^{-x}-1)}{x^2}= \lim_\limits{x\to 0} \frac {(e^x - 1)}{x^2}+ \lim_\limits{x\to 0}\frac {(e^{-x} - 1)}{x^2} $

So, what can you do?

Apply L'Hopital's rule:  Since the denominator has an $x^2$ term to it, you are going to need to do it twice.

$\lim_\limits{x\to 0} \frac {e^x + e^{-x}-2}{x^2} = \lim_\limits{x\to 0} \frac {e^x + e^{-x}}{2} = 1$

Restate the exponentials as Taylor series:  This is very much like applying L'Hopital's rule, at least it is from a theoretical point of view, but once you get the hang of it, I  think, it is much easier to do on complicated limits.

$\lim_\limits{x\to 0} \frac {e^x + e^{-x}-2}{x^2} = \lim_\limits{x\to 0} \frac {(1 + x + \frac {x^2}{2})  + (1 - x + \frac {x^2}{2}) - 2 + O(x^3)}{x^2} = 1$

Get creative:

When I see $e^x + e^{-x}$ I am thinking $2\cosh x.$  And once in this frame of mind what can I do to get rid of the $-2$ hanging at the end....$e^{x} + e^{-x} - 2 = 2\sinh^2 \frac x2$

$\lim_\limits{x\to 0} \frac {2\sinh^2 \frac {x}{2}}{x^2} = 1$

Answer (score 4):

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{x}$$ is not defined. So you can't make arithmetic operations with it like sums.

Comment: But what's the problem with $$\lim_{x\to0} \frac1x - \frac1x = 0 $$

Comment: The problem came from the line above this one. You don't have $$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x} -\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x} =\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \left(\frac{1}{x} -\frac{1}{x}\right)$$ because $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{x}$ is not defined.

Comment: You should also be careful when doing $\frac{e^x - 1}{x} \cdot \frac{1}{x}$.  At the very least, it does different things on either side of $0$.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

I would start with noticing that

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{x} + e^{-x} - 2}{x^{2}} & = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(e^{x/2} - e^{-x/2})^{2}}{x^{2}}\\\\
& = \lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{e^{x/2} - e^{-x/2}}{x}\right)^{2}\\\\
& = \lim_{x\to 0}\left[\frac{(e^{x/2} -1)}{x} - \frac{(e^{-x/2} - 1)}{x}\right]^{2}
\end{align*}

Can you recognize the last expressions as derivatives?

**EDIT**

Based on the request on the comments, here is an improvement of the answer:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{x/2} - 1}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{x/2} - e^{0/2}}{x - 0} = (e^{x/2})'\Bigr|_{\substack{x=0}} = \frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}

Similarly, we do also have that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{-x/2} - 1}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{-x/2} - e^{-0/2}}{x - 0} = (e^{-x/2})'\Bigr|_{\substack{x=0}} = -\frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: No, I'm unable to recognize the last expressions as derivatives. Can explain, please?

Comment: @SiriusBlack sure ! I am going to edit my answer in order to provide the full explanation.